# Linear autoencoders - Will they only preserve linear separable data?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, autoencoders

I'm looking for to compress an image $X$ into a smaller image $x$. But not only compress, also reduce its view into a simplier view that are linear separable.

My question is: Can I use linear autoencoders to turn an image $X$ into a simplier linear image that is linear separable?